# Logging into CAS server using CURL in BASH

Tags: bash, curl, authentication, cas

I've a problem with logging into CAS server using curl in bash command line. CAS server don't want to let me in. After searching the internet for few hours i end with script like this, but still it dosen't work:

```
curl -A "Mozilla/4.73 [en] (X11; U; Linux 2.2.15 i686)" --cookie cjar --cookie-jar cjar --data "username=username" --data "password=password" --data "_eventid=submit" --data "submit=LogIn" --location "https://website.com/cas/login">/tmp/tmp.html
```

Login page looks simple it have 2 texts fields and subbmit button. On the bottom I posted a source code of page (without tables logos paragraph etc.). If anyone have some idea, I'll be very grateful.

```
<form id="fm1" class="fm-v clearfix" action="/cas/login;jsessionid=1B6E23A2038EA3C179126B90B1E4AE3F" method="post">
<label for="username">Login</label>
<input id="username" name="username" class="field" tabindex="1" accesskey="p" type="text" value="" size="25"/>
<label for="password">Password</label>
<input id="password" name="password" class="field" tabindex="2" accesskey="h" type="password" value="" size="25"/>
<input class="button" name="submit" accesskey="l" value="LogIn" tabindex="4" type="submit" />
<script type='text/javascript'>
document.getElementById("fm1").username.focus();
</script>
<input type="hidden" name="lt" value="_c95FE928E-467E-90BA-1B1A-88A86C1DBE7B_k999794A8-58CC-0845-DC1A-1C6C5C6F978B" />
<input type="hidden" name="_eventId" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

lt and *eventId* are fields used in authentication process